# track by $index is not working in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a div in which I use **ng-repeat**. What I have done is repeating the `rfi` from the `rfiList`.

```
<div ng-repeat="rfi in rfiList | orderBy:['isDone','-CreatedDate'] track by $index">
  <button ng-click="closeRFI($index)">Close</button>
</div>
```

In the method `closeRFI($index)`, i am accessing the rfiList using the index

```
var record = $scope.rfiList[index];
```

What is happening here is, when I want to access the `rfiList` using the index, the `rfiList` remains a list before orderby. That is, it seems orderby is not applying in the rfiList and thus index is not changing.

How can I order the `rfiList` so that the index is changed?

Comment: missing double quote  <button ng-click="closeRFI($index)>Close</button>

Comment: Sorry, missed that by mistake. But this is not the cause. Edited the question.

Comment: can you put closeRFI method here?

Comment: Its working right, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0tgL7u6e/416/).

Comment: I am reluctant to re-open this question. The question needs a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is written the error can not be re-produced, as the Fiddle by @Durga shows. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/20451632).

Comment: Get the solution. :) What happened here is, `rfiList[index]` was creating the problem. As `rfiList` is ordered by `orderby`, I thought, list is ordered automatically. But my thought was wrong. The solution I make here is, pass the rfi in `closeRFI` method i.e. `closeRFI(rfi)`. It solved my problem.